# How do I allow user to use their saved photo as a background in my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, user-input

I have been searching around for how to do this sporadically for the last few days and havent been able to find anything and hope you can help.

Currently in my app I have 5 diffrent background as part of the project fils and allow the user to chose between them to set the app background to give some customization aspict to the app.

What I am looking to do is allow the user to select a photo that they have saved on thier device and use that as a background for my app but am unable to find out how to do it or perhaps missed it without knowing (I come from a primarraly C# background so still adjusting to termanology and all the fun things that come with learning a know lang and IDE).

What Im looking to do in code is:

- User clicks to use thier own image
- app opens window to browse through images
- user selects image to use
- assign and save path (or save image in the app somehow)
- set imageview to that image

Thank you everyone for any assistance you can give and the time it takes you to give it. As a FYI Im building for iPhone 5.0

Comment: Use `UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make a UIImageView in nib file and button and hook the nib**

In ViewController.h

```
     @interface ViewController : UIViewController
        <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
    {
       IBOutlet  UIButton *ChooseFileBtn;
    }

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *userimage;
-(IBAction)getphoto:(id)sender;
```

In ViewController.m

```
 -(IBAction)getphoto:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        userimage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        imageView.image=userimage;
    }
```

Comment: You are should not be using the string literal `@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"`. Instead, use the provided constant: `userimage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`

Comment: Thank you so much. So much easier then what I thought was going to be involved. Don't even have to make a new view for the browsing which I thought I had to. :) Meny thanks for your help and the time it took you and all others to put in your answers. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIImagePickerController to get image from Photo library

```
-(void)ClickOnsetBG:(id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *imgpicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgpicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imgpicker.delegate=self;

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imgpicker animated:YES];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Then implement delegate method to get selected image:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {
     UIImage *aImgRecord = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     [imgpicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
     bgImage.image =aImgRecord;

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
 NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"custombg.png"];
     NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(aImgRecord);    
     [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}
```

This image will be saved in document directory of you app. So when you will reopen your app, you will have to set bgimage from This document directory path.

Comment: You are should not be using the string literal `@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"`. Instead, use the provided constant: `UIImage *aImgRecord = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`

Comment: What's the point of the `UIView beginAnimations` and `UIView commitAnimations`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with NSUserDefaults also

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    UIImage *newImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"BackgroundImage"];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {
        // If you have used UIImageView
        [self.yourImageViewObject setImage:newImage];
    }];
}
```

Later the image could be easily shown through NSUserDefaults like

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"BackgroundImage"]];
```